# Change background color of python shell

Tags: python, shell

Is it possible to change background color of the Python Shell from white to black for example. I did find how to change text color, but can't figure out how to change background color. I'm running it under the Windows. Any suggestions?

Comment: That's not specific to Python - it's the same for all command line-thingies. Perhaps more appropriate on super user?

Comment: Perhaps I didn't understand what is "python shell", but you can change `cmd`'s background and foreground colors.

Comment: Change `cmd's` color by using the `color` command.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

if you are refereeing to IDLE i did this simple steps from this link

(its for ubuntu but worked in windows as well)

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=657799

and if you are talking about the windows Prompt , you can use the color command or just right click & select properties & edit the color settings

Comment: If you take the time to do the custom one it looks really cool!

Comment: Since this question and answer, and because of a request posted to bugs.python.org, we added 'IDLE Dark' as a Built-in Theme for current 2.7 and 3.4+.  Like the other built-in themes, it can be altered and saved as a Custom Theme.

Answer (score 4):

Right-click the upper-left corner of the Python console window and select Properties.
In the dialog box that appears, pick the tab labeled Colors. On it you can set the screen background and text color.

[image: scrrens hot]

Answer (score 2):

If you are reffering to the window idle for example for version 2.6 there is now way to change the background color from withe to another one. But you can change the background color of your text if you go to options.
Another thing you can do is to use other gui for python which could be more elaborated such as eclipse pydev or to use a text editor you like and configure it the way you want to write your scripts and then run them into the idle.

Answer (score 2):

just go through simple steps
 - go to options
 - configure IDLE
 - highlighting
 - then select background and click on choose color for: 
 - you can change the color to any color but becareful if u change only the background color the foreground color may not be visible because they both might be black

Enjoy

Answer (score -1):

You can,,go to options then configure IDE, then on the settings window select highlights, on the rightside press the button below a builtin theme, then choose your choice theme